# Chrome is being controlled by automated test software "not secure" data:, Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I'm using the selenium library in python to open google chrome and visit google.com automatically, this is how my script looks like at the moment

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chromedriver = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.accept_untrusted_certs = True
chrome_options.assume_untrusted_cert_issuer = True
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--allow-http-screen-capture")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-impl-side-painting")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-seccomp-filter-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_options("--enable-automation")
chrome_options.add_options("--disable-infobar")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("http://google.com/")
```

My browser tab never displays google.com and it just hangs there [This is the picture of how my browser looks like when I run the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn6b4.png)
[image]

My version of chromedriver is: ChromeDriver 2.39
My Google Chrome version is : Google Chrome 67.0

After doing Ctrl+c, i get this output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "auto-run.py", line 16, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 245, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 472, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 496, in _request
resp = self._conn.getresponse()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Any help as to why --enable-automation does not work would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any error thrown?

Comment: No error thrown, just a blank web page

Answer (score 0):

You are missing full path of chromedriver including **.exe**. Use something like this or fully qualified of chromedriver

```
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='drivers\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: I'm on a Linux machine, not windows

Comment: ok, where is the path of your chrome driver. I mean where it is placed

Answer (score 0):

I modified your script in this way and was able to execute it successfully

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_path  = '/Users/zac/Desktop/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver'
#this would be the path to the chromedriver exe on your system

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.accept_untrusted_certs = True
chrome_options.assume_untrusted_cert_issuer = True
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--allow-http-screen-capture")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-impl-side-painting")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-seccomp-filter-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("http://google.com/")
```

Also, you need to use `add-argument` and not `add_options` for the `--enable-automation` flag

Comment: I copied and pasted your script and modified my path to chrome_path  = '/usr/bin/chromedriver' , and did chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-automation") but still no luck :\

Comment: Do not keep it in the `/usr/bin` folder. Change to somewhere you have executable permissions.  Best place would be keep it in your Downloads folder under a new folder called drivers.. like `/usr/your_name/Downloads/driver/chromedriver`

Comment: Done., but still no luck

Comment: Also, go inside the folder where you've kept chromedriver and do `chmod +x chromedriver.exe`

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately, I've edited my question and included the stack trace after doing ctrl+c